# Using AudioGraph to stream sound from a url?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, win-universal-app, audio-streaming

I am trying to use AudioGraph in my UWP application to stream sound from an URL.

```
var soundFile = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("stream.mp3", new Uri("http://some.url"), null);
var streamResult = await _audioGraph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(soundFile);
```

However this is not working, is there any other way of streaming a never ending file from an URL? I can play music/sound from a local file on my computer without any issues, but this is not really what I want to do.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can I know if the source can be downloaded by the url?  What do you want to with the audio, just play?  What is the technology used for the audio stream?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Thanks for the comment. The source cannot be downloaded (at least not completely) since it's justa a never ending stream. I just want to play and I actually solved my issue with the MediaPlayer class instead.

Don't know about the technology behind the stream since I am just creating a consuming client, but I suppose it's in mp3 format.

Comment: So you have resolved right?  If just for playing, `AudioGraph` is no needed.

Comment: Yes it is resolved.